# Java: Handling large files in input streams

Tags: java, zip, large-files, file-transfer

I have a Java app that fetches a relatively small `.zip` file using a `URL`, saves it in a temp directory, unzips it onto the local machine and makes some changes to one of the files. This all works great.

However, I am accessing the `.zip` file via a `BufferedInputStream` in the following way:

```
Url url = "http://somedomain.com/file.zip";
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 1024);
```

My concern is that this app will actually be used to transfer *very* large `zip` files and I was wondering if a `BufferedInputStream` is actually the best way to do this, or whether I would just end up throwing some type of `OutOfMemoryException`?

So my question is, will a `BufferedInputStream` be suitable for this job, or should I be going about it in a completely different way?

Comment: You probably want to use a library to handle this. File uploads are an easy DOS entry point. Take a look at the FileUpload class in Apache Commons Fileupload.

Comment: @Perception where is he uploading? He just downloads the file and unzips it.

Comment: @Viruzzo - point taken. The process he is describing sounds very much like a file upload, though a file *transfer* would have been more appropriate terminology in my comment.

Comment: @Perception actually it's nothing like an upload: he doesn't receive the file contents (as it would happen in a POST/PUT upload), he just GETs a file and saves it locally. Moreover, in a usual HTTP server environment this part would be handled by the server itself automatically.

Comment: Handled automatically? By what exactly? It's like a file upload in-as-much as he has an incoming stream of data from a remote source that he is saving locally. But as I've already said it is indeed more accurate to refer to the process as a file transfer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) doesn't load all the file into memory, it only uses an internal buffer, in your case of size 1024 bytes = 1kb. It never gets larger than that. You could actually increase the value if you aren't going to have many streams at once.

Edit: what you are thinking about maybe is a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), where data is saved in memory.

Comment: Thanks, your answer and the link were really helpful. This stream should be the only one run at a time so I will look at increasing the size.

Comment: In regards to your edit, I think you are right - I have come across an out of memory error when working with inputstreams (hence my concern), and I think I was actually working with the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you do with the content you read. If you read everything in memory, it will fail. If you write it to another stream, then it will be fine. Use `BufferedInputStream`

Comment: "saves it in a temp directory" so he's writing it to disk.

Answer (score 1):

From the official [Java Tutorials - Buffered Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html):

> The Java platform implements buffered I/O streams. Buffered input
>   streams read data from a memory area known as a buffer; the native
>   input API is called only when the buffer is empty. Similarly, buffered
>   output streams write data to a buffer, and the native output API is
>   called only when the buffer is full.

There is another great [SUN article](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPIOPerformance.fm.html).

So the answer is: `BufferedInputStream` is suitable for this kind of job in the sense of performance.

And yes, the memory consumption isn't so much dependent on the type of the input stream....